# how to convert string dict to dictonary in python

Tags: python, django

```
a= {'Locator__creation_date': {'start': datetime.date(2013, 11, 14), 'end': datetime.date(2013, 11, 14)}, 'Locator__employed': u'True', 'Locator__employer_state': u'AL', 'Locator__receiving_hiv_treatment': u'True', 'Locator__hiv_treatment_state': u'AR', 'Locator__mental_health_provider': u'False', 'Locator__parole': u'True', 'Locator__parole_state': u'IA', 'data_model_name': ['Locator']}

ast.literal_eval(a)
```

it gives

```
ValueError: malformed string
```

Comment: You are passing in a *Python object*, not a string.

Comment: You also have `datetime` objects in there, those won't work with `ast.literal_eval()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Presumably you meant `a` to be a string:

```
a = "{'Locator__creation_date': {'start': datetime.date(2013, 11, 14), 'end': datetime.date(2013, 11, 14)}, 'Locator__employed': u'True', 'Locator__employer_state': u'AL', 'Locator__receiving_hiv_treatment': u'True', 'Locator__hiv_treatment_state': u'AR', 'Locator__mental_health_provider': u'False', 'Locator__parole': u'True', 'Locator__parole_state': u'IA', 'data_model_name': ['Locator']}"
```

This won't work because `datetime.date(...)` is not a Python literal. It is a representation of a Python `datetime.date()` object, and `ast.literal_eval()` does not handle arbitrary types.

*Only* Python literal values (`{...}` for dictionaries or sets, `[...]` for lists, `(...)` for tuples, digits to numbers and string literals such as `u'...'` and `r'...'` and `'...'` with the various quote variations) are handled. See the [Literals section of the Python expressions documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#literals) and the [`ast.literal_eval()` documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval) itself:

> The string or node provided may only consist of the following Python literal structures: strings, numbers, tuples, lists, dicts, booleans, and `None`.